# vuelidate - How to display custom validation message with built-in validators

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuelidate

I am using vuelidate library for validating my forms. I have to use the built-in validators with the custom message. I have tried below. But not working.  Ref: [Vuelidate Form validation library](https://vuelidate-next.netlify.app/)

```
validations() {
   return {
     email: {
       requiredIf: requiredIf(() => {
         return this.data.enablevalidation;
       }),
       email: helpers.withMessage(this.data.validation_err_message, email),
     },
   };
},
```

my problem is, If the validation is false, still its validating the email also. Validation should be pass based on the both condition. If validation false, Email validation also should not work. How to achieve this scenario

Comment: can you please add your HTML code as well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have to use the helpers with functional method to achieve this.

```
validations () {
   return {
     email: {
       requiredIf: helpers.withMessage(this.data.validation_err_message, 
          requiredIf(() => {
            return this.data.enablevalidation
       })),
       email: helpers.withMessage(this.data.validation_err_message, email),
     }
   }
},
```

Initiallty it will validate, whether this field have to validate or not. If validation is true, It will display the given message. Email will be validate if given wrong.

Comment: how can we set it globally for a particular validation. Like a required validation throws error like Value is required. How can we set it globally like where ever required validation is used throw error msg like This field is required ??

Comment: As per my knowledge, Vuediate is validating based on the variable we have referred in v-model. 
so I don't think globally is not possible. Can any other provide your input